# Modal window with just CSS

Tags: javascript, css, popup, modal-dialog

Is this possible, or do I have to use JavaScript to set modal height to body height? for example:

```
$('.modal').height($('body').height())
```

I can't use this CSS:

```
.modal{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Because modal parent height is calculated according other children.

Comment: use `position: absolute`, which removes the element from document flow and makes its layout parent the browser window instead?

Comment: oh, that works, but now I am having another problem, going to create a Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS as you list above but use absolute positioning.

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Just remember that the element will be positioned relative to it's first positioned ancestor.

So, if you want this to be positioned relative to the top left corner of the browser, make sure the modal element is not nested inside of another positioned element elsewhere on the page.